# Alternate Access Mappings affecting Page Layouts

Tags: 2010, page-layout, alternate-access-mapping

I have recently changed our url from http ://servername to http ://urlname
I changed the AAM to reflect this as well as alter the binding in IIS

It seems to work fine but when ever I create a new publishing page site I receive the following error - 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetWebUrl(Guid gWebId, String bstrSiteUrl)

If I revert the AAM back it works fine.

It seems to me that SharePoint still points to http ://servername/(path for page layouts) no matter how AAM is configured.

HELP!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you don't change the url of a SharePoint web application behind the back of SharePoint. And ajusting the AAM doesn't make that valid.

Instead you should delete the web application and create it using the new url, but the old content databases

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable and enable the publishing feature in the site collection level. Additionally, make sure your masterpages do not refer to any files or scripts with absolute urls that contains hostnames before you enabled AAM.